# How do you pronounce the name 'Çeda'?

Tags: pronunciation

The name of the protagonist of Bradley P. Beaulieu's *The Song of the Shattered Sands* series is Çeda.

What is the correct pronunciation of this name and which language inspired it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this Goodreads discussion](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/524264-how-do-you-pronounce-eda-i-don-t-know-if):

> **Sana** It's pronounced as 'Chayda.'
>
> **Jayden** Actually the answer is rather early in the book itself :) That endeared the author a lot to me. It's hidden in a conversation between her and her mother, or in her thoughts to it.

As per fez's comment, this was also answered by the author in a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/3l24fk/hi_im_bradley_p_beaulieu_cheese_lover_and_author/cv34htl/):

> **bradbeaulieuAMA** *Author Bradley P. Beaulieu* [S] 3 points *2 years ago*
>
> I'm glad you liked Irindai! The reception to that story has really been great.
> Çeda is pronounced CHAY-da, similar to Aveda, or mesa.

The [wiki](http://shatteredsands.wikia.com/wiki/Sharakhani) notes that it's short for "*Çedamihn Ahyanesh'ala* or Child of Ahyanesh".

As for likely etymology, [Turkish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7#Turkish) and [Turkmen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7#Turkmen) both pronounce the C cedilla with a "ch" sound. That fits with the general feel of the setting I got from reading the sample chapters, rug sellers and carpets and stone buildings.

Comment: I'll admit, I have not read the book in question, so I don't know what "conversation" that is. It doesn't seem to be in the three sample chapters.

Comment: i started with vol 2 called blood upon the sand (this is what i found on the train's library) so I've no idea :P

Comment: To add to your post, the author did an AMA on reddit and said exactly the same :) https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/3l24fk/hi_im_bradley_p_beaulieu_cheese_lover_and_author/cv34htl/

Comment: Turkish?  FINALLY not the default medieval western european setting.